# Big and Little Endian System with Network Byte Order

Tags: networking, tcp

Recently, I am studying TCP/IP and I try to understand the relationship between Big, Little Endian and Network Byte Order. I want someone to point out that whether there is a problem in my understanding.

The premise:

1. Assuming that Store address increases from left to right in turn.
2. For the sake of simplicity, use decimal system not binary, eg, 12 means twelve and it takes two bytes: 1 take a byte and 2 take a byte.
3. Assuming A is Big endian machine and B is Little endian machine.
4. TCP provide network byte order is Big Endian.
5. All by system default, no additional operation to convert.

The following is my understanding(I will give the serial number, if there is a problem you can point out the number):

1. In A, the number 12(As mentioned earlier in premise 2) storage form is 12(lower address is 1 and higher address is 2). In B, storage form is 21(lower address is 2 and higher address is 1)
2. Network Byte Order is Big endian, so when a machine send data to network it will send the data in lower address first, then the data in higher address. Similarly a machine receive data from network will think the data first be received is higher-bit of data (by default). Is that right?
3. A send data 12 to B. A will first send lower address data that is 1, then send 2. B receives 1 and B think 1 is higher-bit of data so it stores 1 in higher address and stores 2 in lower address, that is 21. When B read the received data from memory it is 12. There is no problem.
4. B send data 12 to A. Similarly B will first send lower address data that is 2, then send 1. A receives 2 and think 2 is hight-bit of data so A stores 2 in lower address and stores 1 in higher address, that is 21. When A read the received data from memory it is 21. There is a problem cause 12 is the right number not 21.
5. From what has been discussed above, Big Endian send data to Little Endian will be OK but Little Endian send data to Big Endian will cause a problem. Is that right?

Comment: The network stack on a particular host will translate to and from the network byte order, regardless of the endianness of the host system.

Comment: @RonMaupin i do not understand,can you for example? From discussing above,12 store in B( Little endian) is 21,if B send data 12 how the network stack will translate to the network byte order? 12 or 21 ? and how it will translate from the network byte order if B receives data 12? thank you.